# Kafka Streams Join - KTable not yet loaded

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Need to join `KStream` with `KTable`. As keys happen not to be the same, I created a helper `JoinStreamTableTransformer` which allows to provide a `KeyValueMapper` similar to a left join `KStream`/`GlobalKTable`. This all works fine.

The actual problem is that there seem to be a delay until `KTable` gets loaded and hence the join operation (`transformValues(new JoinStreamTableTransformer ... )`) fails as there are no corresponding values in the `KTable` i.e. right value `rV` is `null`. In debugger I can see, that unfortunately table gets loaded after the join.

Have tried to set `max.task.idle.ms` e.g. to `1000` as well as `commit.interval.ms` to `100` but no luck.
Below a simplified version of my topology

```
// harmonize/normalize data
KStream<RawKey,HB> hb = builder
    .stream("Raw_Topic", Consumed.with(rawKeySerde, rawSerde))
    // enrich each record ...
    .leftJoin(...);

// "store" entities in individual topics    
hb.map((key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(value.getA().getKey(), value.getA().getValue()))
    .to("A_Topic", Produced.with(aKeySerde, aSerde, new APartitioner()));
hb.map((key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(value.getB().getKey(), value.getB().getValue()))
    .to("B_Topic", Produced.with(bKeySerde, bSerde, new BPartitioner()));
hb.map((key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(value.getC().getKey(), value.getC().getValue()))
    .to("C_Topic", Produced.with(cKeySerde, cSerde, new CPartitioner()));

// prepare lookup tables used further below         
KTable<AKey, A> aLookup = builder
    .stream("A_Topic", Consumed.with(aKeySerde, aSerde))
    .selectKey((k, v) -> { k.setSnapshotAsOf(null); return k; })
    .repartition(Repartitioned.with(aKeySerde, aSerde).withStreamPartitioner(new APartitioner()))
    .toTable(Named.as("LATEST_A_LKP"), Materialized.with(aKeySerde, aSerde));

KTable<BKey, B> bLookup = builder
    .stream("B_Topic", Consumed.with(bKeySerde, bSerde))
    .selectKey((k, v) -> { k.setSnapshotAsOf(null); return k; })
    .repartition(Repartitioned.with(bKeySerde, bSerde).withStreamPartitioner(new BPartitioner()))
    .toTable(Named.as("LATEST_B_LKP"), Materialized.with(bKeySerde, bSerde));

// emit uptdated records
builder.stream("C_Topic", Consumed.with(cKeySerde, cSerde))
    .leftJoin(...)
    .flatMap(...)
    .repartition(...)
    .leftJoin(...)
    .flatMap(...) // result is KStream<HBUKey, HBU>

    .transformValues(new JoinStreamTableTransformer<HBUKey, HBU, AKey, A>(
        aLookup,
        // KeyValueMapper<? super K, ? super V, ? extends KT>
        (lK, lV) -> lV.getAKey(),
        // ValueJoiner<? super V, ? super V, ? extends RV>
        (lK, lV, rV) -> lV.setA(rV),
        ((KTableImpl) aLookup).valueGetterSupplier().storeNames())

    .transformValues(new JoinStreamTableTransformer<HBUKey, HBU, BKey, B>(
        bLookup,
        (lK, lV) -> lV.getBKey(),
        (lK, lV, rV) -> lV.setB(rV),
        ((KTableImpl) aLookup).valueGetterSupplier().storeNames())

// ...
```

Kafka version is 3.1.1